# Convert String array to JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json, javafx, gff

I am trying to parse a GFF file and search for a particular gene ID, and if found, convert the whole row of that gene ID into an element of a JSONArray.

However, when I do the above, the column headers are not present in the array:

```
try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
    json = "";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {

        if (line.contains("Solyc02g065040")){
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
            System.out.println(sb);

        }
        else{
            //do nothing
        }
    }

    json = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(json);
    reader.close();

    String [] gffArray = json.split("\n");
    System.out.println(gffArray);



    JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < gffArray.length; i++) {
        jsArray.put(gffArray[i]);
    }

    System.out.println(jsArray);
```

The output looks like this:

```
["SL3.0ch02\tmaker_ITAG\tgene\t36723123\t36723359\t.\t-\t.\tID=gene:Solyc02g065040.1;Alias=Solyc02g065040;Name=Solyc02g065040.1;length=236"]
```

Whereas I wanted it to look like this, retaining headers:

```
["seqname":"SL3.0ch02", "source":"maker_ITAG","feature":"gene", "start":"36723123", "end":"36723359","attribute":"ID=gene:Solyc02g065040.1;Alias=Solyc02g065040;Name=Solyc02g065040.1;length=236"]
```

I need it to be like this so that I can populate a table in javafx according to these by saying:

```
(jsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("seqname"))
(jsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("gene"))
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: if you know a little js: http://spareinformatics.blogspot.com/2014/01/converting-gff-files-to-json-in.html

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly. And how is this related to fx?